# how to use capcha code in the asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can add capcha code in the asp.net registration form

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper in web matrix.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611

Answer (score 0):

There is a [captcha control sample on Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx) for asp.net 1.1 and 2.0

[image]

And on codeplex there is one for .net 3.5 - [MyCaptcha is a free opensoruce ASP.NET Captcha control written in C# 3.0.](http://mycaptcha.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Googles [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is pretty neat and very popular. Lot's of examples to get up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [using reCAPTCHA with ASP.NET](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

http://viralsarvaiya.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/arithmetic-captcha-in-asp-net/

http://viralsarvaiya.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/how-to-generate-captcha-image-in-asp-net/